# Songs in the music player application are played together

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I want the previous song to stop when I start another song - But currently, it plays them together

I've tried `mediaPlayer.stop()` and `mediaPlayer.release()` but this didn't work

Should I do this in the `Parcalar` class? You can find the codes of my two classes at the bottom

---

Also, Seekbar has a problem - When I play music, Seekbar is coming to the final position. But first I want to solve my first problem

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;
    boolean isPaused;
    private ArrayList<String> musicNames;
    private double startTime = 0;
    private double finalTime = 0;

    private Handler myHandler= new Handler();
    private SeekBar seekBar;

    private int forwardTime = 5000;
    private int backwardTime = 5000;
    private ImageView playPause;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private TextView textView1,textView2,textView3;

    public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;

    public ArrayList<String> getMusicNames() {
        return musicNames;
    }

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return mediaPlayer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playPause = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView2.setText("Song.Mp3");
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final int position = bundle.getInt("position");
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.neureich);
        seekBar.setClickable(false);

        musicNames=new ArrayList<String>();
        musicNames.add("neureich");
        musicNames.add("neureichkisa");
        musicNames.add("traviscotthighestinthroom");

        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            int u = getResources().getIdentifier(musicNames.get(position), "raw", "com.example.myapplication");
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);


        }
        else{
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            int u = getResources().getIdentifier(musicNames.get(position), "raw", "com.example.myapplication");
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }

        playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                        if(fromUser)
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                        textView1.setText(String.format ("%d min,%d sec",
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)startTime),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long)startTime)-
                                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)//
                                                startTime)))
                        );
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }
                });
                isPaused=false;
                if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();


                    if(oneTimeOnly == 0){
                        seekBar.setMax((int)finalTime);
                        oneTimeOnly = 1;
                    }
                    textView3.setText(String.format ("%d min,%d sec",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)finalTime),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long)finalTime)- //172-52
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)//toplam saniyeyi dakikaya çeviriyor
                                            finalTime)))

                    );

                    textView1.setText(String.format ("%d min,%d sec",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)startTime),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long)startTime)-
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)//
                                            startTime)))

                    );
                    seekBar.setProgress((int) startTime);
                    myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);
                    playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);


                }

                else{
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    isPaused=true;
                    playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
                }

            }
        });


    }
    private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            textView1.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                    toMinutes((long) startTime)))
            );
            seekBar.setProgress((int)startTime);
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
}
```

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Parcalar extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parcalar);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position",position);
            startActivity(intent);


            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881684/how-do-you-play-audio-file-sequentially-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you play audio file sequentially in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881684/how-do-you-play-audio-file-sequentially-in-java)

Comment: My problem is when I open a different track while playing the track.Two tracks playing together

Comment: What prevents you from stopping playback before starting a new track?

Comment: I'm stopping at else.But it doesn't go to else.